# Xcode Build Error on Flutter Any Object Error and openURL error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm having an issue with my project. I get this bunch of Error on Build on Xcode (developing on Visual Studio Code).

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           1456.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Albums/AlbumsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AlbumsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Assets/AssetsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AssetsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Controller/ImagePickerControllerDelegate.swift:27:48: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    public protocol ImagePickerControllerDelegate: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Albums/AlbumsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AlbumsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Assets/AssetsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AssetsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Controller/ImagePickerControllerDelegate.swift:27:48: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    public protocol ImagePickerControllerDelegate: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Albums/AlbumsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AlbumsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Scene/Assets/AssetsViewController.swift:26:40: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    protocol AssetsViewControllerDelegate: class {
                                           ^~~~~
                                           AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/BSImagePicker/Sources/Controller/ImagePickerControllerDelegate.swift:27:48: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    public protocol ImagePickerControllerDelegate: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/transport/client_auth_filter.cc:32:
    In file included from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.h:28:
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:36:
    In file included from /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/context_list.h:26:
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:109:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_chttp2_ping_queue
    /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:110:52: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_closure_list lists[GRPC_CHTTP2_PCL_COUNT] = {};
                                ^
    Failed to package /Users/usuario/development/projects/stb/property1.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
Exited (sigterm)
```

This happened out of the blue with no issues until this morning. I had before an Issue with:

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99
```

which I think it got Solved using:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

In the PodFile.

Then I still got this error, the one I'm consulting for, so I tried updating my Flutter from 2.2.0 to 2.5.0, and I updated my dependencies from:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.7.5
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  algolia: ^1.0.1
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.4
  share: ^2.0.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.0.0
  csc_picker: ^0.2.5
  us_states: ^1.1.0
  multi_image_picker2: ^5.0.2
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  flutter_material_pickers: ^3.1.0 #used on Selling Bathrooms and Bedrooms
  numberpicker: ^2.1.1 #used on Selling Bedrooms only.
  eva_icons_flutter: ^3.0.0
  badges: ^2.0.1
  flutter_xlider: ^3.4.0
  expandable_text: 2.2.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  intl_phone_field: ^2.0.1 #used to get the phone in the Profile Page.
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0 #used to do the mask of the Filters TextFormField to Dollar Value, not use currently
  flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6 #used to get the file path for multi Image 
  rxdart: ^0.27.2 #used for Geolocation queries with Firebase
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6
```

To:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^6.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+1
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.3
  random_string: ^2.3.1
  algolia: ^1.0.1
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  google_sign_in: ^5.1.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.9
  share: ^2.0.4
  #flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.0.0
  csc_picker: ^0.2.5
  us_states: ^1.1.5
  multi_image_picker2: ^5.0.2
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  flutter_material_pickers: ^3.1.0 #used on Selling Bathrooms and Bedrooms
  numberpicker: ^2.1.1 #used on Selling Bedrooms only.
  eva_icons_flutter: ^3.0.2
  badges: ^2.0.1
  flutter_xlider: ^3.4.0
  expandable_text: ^2.2.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.9
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  intl_phone_field: ^2.1.0 #used to get the phone in the Profile Page.
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0 #used to do the mask of the Filters TextFormField to Dollar Value, not use currently
  #flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6 #used to get the file path for multi Image 
  rxdart: ^0.27.2 #used for Geolocation queries with Firebase
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.7
```

Obviously, updating my code to reflect the changes, any ideas on how to get it back in the iOS simulator and working back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one faces this issue, I manage a Fix, first here I was facing 2 Issues:

1. The Pods of my Projects weren't working anymore due to the support drop for iOS 8 in Xcode 12 (More info in [Link](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/07/20/xcode-12-drops-support-for-ios-8-fix-for-cocoapods/)).
2. In my efforts to make it work I updated from Flutter 2.2.0 to 2.5.0 which basically makes a lot of changes and takes support away from some methods, which Dependencies rely on.

To fix this I did 2 things:

Starting with issue 2, I just made a downgrade to my Flutter by ussing the command ***flutter downgrade 2.2.0*** this help me get back to my original issue without facing the Methods taken away of those dependecies.

As for Issue 1 there were to things:

First added this into the PodFile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Secondly to fix the Pods I did the following steps:

1. Delete the pubspec.lock file.

- In terminal of the main Project

2. Did a Flutter Clean.

- In terminal going to the iOS Folder:

3. Delete the Podfile.lock
4. Delete the Pods Folder.
5. CRUCIAL: Copy (where ever as a backup) the Content of the PodFile including the part added at the end.
6. Delete the Podfile.
7. In Terminal in iOS Folder do a pod init. (This will Generate the Podfile with basic info).
8. In Terminal in iOS Folder do a pod install. (This will Generate the Podfile.lock and the Pods folder with basic info).

- Navigate to the main Project folder in Terminal (cd ..) or use the Pub get icon in the pubspec.yaml file.

9. Do a flutter pub get

- In terminal going to the iOS Folder:

10. Copy the stored information backed up in Step 5, and pasted in the PodFile.
11. Do a pod install.

- Navigate to the main Project folder in Terminal (cd ..)

Finally, just do a flutter run.

This was how I manage to solve it.

Kind Regards